# Managing menu ito database in website builder

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

I am building website builder that allows users to create website in asp.net c#. Now what is the best way to store menu into database.Should I store whole html (`<ul> <li>` ) into database or create a separate table that would store menu specific details for all users??

Comment: That surely depends on your needs... This is a design question, and if I understood your question, you can do it either way so go with what you think is better (easier to manage, create and maintain)

Answer (score 0):

While this can be a mater of preference I would strongly suggest not placing the HTML markup in the database.  By placing the markup in the database you make changing anything about that markup much more difficult.  While good planning can limit the need to change the markup it isn't possible to see all potential changes you may want to make.

The article "[Dynamically populating menu items from the database in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/354696/Dynamically-populating-menu-items-from-the-databas)" is a good introduction to creating a dynamic database driven menu.